# Como concatenar um resultado de um case com outros campos?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Exemplo:

```
select x+y+
    case
    when 2>1 then 'z'
    else 'w'
    end 
from table
```

Resultado esperado: xyz

O código acima resulta em erro.
Não encontrei nada parecido...
Admitindo que todos sejam campos de mesmo tipo.

Comment: Que tal passar tudo pra depois do `then`,  exemplo:
`select 
    case
    when 2>1 then x+y+z
    else x+y+w
    end 
from table`

Answer (score 0):

Os itens a serem somados ou concatenados precisam ser do mesmo tipo do valor a ser retornado pelo trecho `case...when`, fiz um exemplo utilizando o `cast` para explicitar o tipo pretendido.
No seu caso, o problema pode ser que algum campo seja diferente do que está sendo retornado pela expressão `case...when`.

**Considerando seu exemplo, ficaria assim:**

```
  select cast(Coalesce(x,'') as varchar) + cast(Coalesce(y,'') as varchar) + 
    case
       when 2>1 then 'z'
       else 'w'
    end  
  from table
```

`Coalesce(x,'')` é para prevenir erro caso o campo esteja nulo.

**No caso de ser texto:**

```
  select cast('x' as varchar) + cast('y' as varchar) + 
    case
       when 2>1 then 'z'
       else 'w'
    end
```

Resultado: xyz

**No caso de números inteiros:**

```
  select cast('3' as int) + cast('4' as int) + 
    case
       when 2>1 then 4
       else 6
    end
```

Resultado: 11

Não coloquei tabela nos dois últimos exemplos, pois não é necessário incluir o `from table` nesses casos. Execute para verificar se resolve o problema e adeque a sua necessidade.

Comment: Inclui no início o exemplo fornecido pelo usuário considerando x e y como campos da tabela. Considerei a possibilidade de valor nulo causar problema na execução da consulta, prevenindo tal erro com o `Coalesce`.